# vim: can non active tab being completely hidden, no headers show /c/e/n alike

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

When open multiple tabs, it will show in the topmost line something `/c/e/n...` alike.

But I already has filename and `&modified` in status line, which just waste space then.
Also I find that line quite distracting.

**Is there any way hide non active tabs completely?**

Comment: `:h 'showtabline'`?

Comment: thx, that's what I want, should I delete question?

Comment: No, you can answer your own question. It would be better for newer users if you wrote an intelligible answer explaining the usage of `:h showtabline` in lieu of the just deleting the question.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to answer your question. You can edit it if you like, and then accept it as the correct answer if it did serve your purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like `:h 'laststatus'`, you can customize when you want your `:h 'tabline'` to show.

According to `:h 'showtabline'`, you can set the value of the variable *showtabline* to any of the following numbers with associated significance following those numbers below.

```
    The value of this option specifies when the line with tab page labels
    will be displayed:
        0: never
        1: only if there are at least two tab pages
        2: always
```

So, in your case, you will need to set the variable *showtabline* to zero in order for it to be never shown. You can do that in either of the following manners.

```
:set showtabline=0
:let &showtabline=0
```